# How to skip headers in csv file when headers exists

Tags: java, csv, apache-commons-csv

I am using apache-common-csv to import data from the CSV file and I would like to skip headers in the first line. What is important, the file sometimes can contain headers but sometimes not. 
I have an implementation like below but the result not satisfying me, because when the file is without headers the first line is cutting.

```
CSVFormat.DEFAULT
        .withDelimiter(';')
        .withHeader(HEADERS)
        .withSkipHeaderRecord()
        .parse(InputStreamReadersource.inputStream)
```

Comment: I would form a String by combining the header words and compare if the first line of csv is same as this String. Won't it solve your issue ?

Comment: you're right. I did a filter to compare two strings and it's works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think this could help you.

```
CSVFormat.RFC4180
         .withFirstRecordAsHeader()
         .withDelimiter(';').parse(InputStreamReadersource.inputStream);
```

Here is the reference on Commons CSV user guide https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/user-guide.html

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, since it *always* skips the first record, even if it isn't a header.